# node js express 3 app.post not working

Tags: mysql, ajax, node.js, express

I am having problems when trying to do a post. my app.get works perfectly, but I cannot say the same for the post. This is my server.js

```
// Express is the web framework 
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.configure(function () {
  app.use(allowCrossDomain);
});

app.post('/server/orders',express.bodyParser(), function(req, res) { 
     alert("Estamoooo");
    console.log("POST Order"); 
    var client = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    database : "DB",
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'XXXX'
    });
    client.connect(); 


    var name = req.body.name; 
    var lastname = req.body.lastname; 
    var telephone = req.body.telephone; 
    var address = req.body.address; 
    var queso = req.body.queso; 
    var vainilla = req.body.vainilla; 
    var date = req.body.date;


    var query = client.query("insert into orden(name,lastname,telephone,address,queso,vainilla,date) values('"  
    + name + "', '" + lastname +"','"+ telephone +"'  , "+ address + ", '" + queso + "', "+ vainilla +", '" + date  
    +"' );"); 
    query.on("end", function (result) { 
        client.end(); 
        res.json(true); 
    }); 

 });
```

and this is my appjs.js

```
function addOrder(){ 
    var newOrder = {}; 
    newOrder.name = document.getElementById("nombre").value; 
    newOrder.lastname = document.getElementById("apellido").value; 
    newOrder.telephone = document.getElementById("telefono").value; 
    newOrder.address = document.getElementById("direccion").value; 
    newOrder.queso = document.getElementById("cantidadQueso").value; 
    newOrder.vainilla = document.getElementById("cantidadVainilla").value; 
    newOrder.date = document.getElementById("fecha").value; 

    var newOrderJSON = JSON.stringify(newOrder); 
    alert("New Order: " + newOrderJSON);
    $.ajax({
        url : "http://192.168.0.1:8020/server/orders",
        method: 'post',
        data : newOrderJSON,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType:"json",
        success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            alert("Data Added!!!");
        },
        error: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            alert("Data could not be added!");
        }
        }); 
 }
```

The ajax is not being called. I do not get a response, just nothing happens. It's strange because the get works really great. Thanks!

UPDATE: I do know that the server side works great. The problem is in the appjs code. It is skipping the ajax call.

Comment: Is your client code executed? Btw you don't need to stringify the data variable: `JSON.stringify(newOrder)`. Just pass it how it is: `data : newOrder,`

Comment: yes it is executed. is just a button that has an onclick="addOrder()" Actually I can get the alert just before the ajax, but thats it. Nothing else.

Comment: Does the request reach the server (check in Your browser network monitor)? If yes, does the server return any debug messages?

Comment: No, I do not get any message to the console. Is like it jumps over the ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot the `app.listen(8020);` part.

I tested the example below:

```
// Express is the web framework 
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/server/orders',express.bodyParser(), function(req, res) { 
    console.log("POST Order"); 

    var name = req.body.name; 
    var lastname = req.body.lastname; 
    var telephone = req.body.telephone; 
    var address = req.body.address; 
    var queso = req.body.queso; 
    var vainilla = req.body.vainilla; 
    var date = req.body.date;

    console.log(name, lastname, telephone, address, queso, vainilla, date);

    res.send('works');
 });

app.listen(8020);
```

With the following command:

```
curl -v -XPOST 'localhost:8020/server/orders' -d "name=name value&lastname=lastname value&telephone=telephone value&address=address value&queso=queso value&vainilla=vainilla value&date=date value"
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8020 (#0)
> POST /server/orders HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: localhost:8020
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 145
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 145 out of 145 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 5
< Date: Tue, 06 Jan 2015 16:42:35 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
works%
```

As you can see it works.

Comment: I have the app.listen(8020);
Still doesnt work. Let me try your code.

Comment: Still doesnt work. The ajax is not getting called. That is strange

Comment: Ok, got it to work with your code. I was having problems with the alert. it works now when i use the curl -v -XPOST 'localhost:8020/server/orders' -d "name=name value&lastname=lastname value&telephone=telephone value&address=address value&queso=queso value&vainilla=vainilla value&date=date value", but not when called from the ajax. It is still not calling the ajax which means the server is fine, the problem is in the addOrder method.

Comment: I have tried everything. I still dont know what to do

Comment: @JosephOcasio first and foremost congratulations. It was an important step to separate the issue. Now that you know that's browser related it should be easy peasy. Which browser are you using? Do you know chrome's debug tools? If not, check out [the network monitor](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network). I would inspect if the request is made and if yes, which response you get. Try to make the ajax request as simple as possible. I also recommend to use the `console.log()` method instead of `alert` - will make your life easier.

Comment: Hello, I found out why it was skipping the AJAX. I forgot to include the Jquery library. You have been a lot of help thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to put the include on my html of jquery, that is why the ajax block of code was being skipped.